# c++ array returning erroneous characters

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Currently having an issue with the following code returning an array with symbols appended to the end.  This is the smallest I could get the code in order to reproduce the error.  What is causing this issue?  I assume that maybe the array is getting numbers in it somehow which get interpreted as ascii symbols, but I can't figure out where this is happening.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int numRow = 6;
const int numCol = 26;

char letters[numRow][numCol] = {

    { 'm', 'w', 'r', 'u', 't', 'v', 'n', 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'n', 'x', 'm', 'd', 'q', 'y', 'u', 't' },
    { 'y', 'e', 'r', 'y', 'e', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'x', 'z' },
    { 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'n', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g' },
    { 'y', 'e', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'b' },
    { 'e', 'r', 'y', 'e', 't', 't', 'v', 'n', 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'g' },
    { 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h' }
};






int main()
{

    char *ltrptr;
    ltrptr = &letters[0][0];

    const int arraySize = 6 * 26;
    int answer = 0;

    cout << " Select row for sort: " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    char newArray[numCol];
    char *ltrptr2;
    ltrptr2 = &newArray[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < numCol; i++){
        newArray[i] = letters[answer - 1][i];

    }
    cout << "Selected row: before" << newArray << endl;
    selectionSort(ltrptr2, numCol, ascending);
    cout << "Selected row: after " << newArray << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running it in debug mode, failing that try `-march=sparc3`

Comment: Is `selectionSort` a windows thing, or is this not a complete example?

Comment: Your example [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/hk2X7EE), provide a [MCVE] please!

Comment: Hey, just down vote this because I copied a portion that I did not mean to.  Sorry for the terrible question ha.  SelectionSort is just a function used for sorting, but it's not supposed to be a part of the example as the error occurs before that is called anyways.  Additionally, I wish to add that I am trying to call a specific row from the 2d array.  I will post up input and output screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you actually included what output you got and what output you expected (and also the input given), rather than trying to describe the output.

But your code has an obvious error which is consistent with your vague description: you haven't put a C string in your character array, but you try to print it as if it did contain a C string.

(in particular, to store a C string in a character array, one must store the sequence of characters *followed by a null character*)

Comment: Ok I put the array in a for loop and it corrected the issue.  Thanks man.  Should I post the corrected code?